# Postgresql, jsonb with multiple keys is returning a single row for each key

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Here's what my situation is. I have rows that have a json column, and what I've been trying to do is get all the values for all the keys in that json in just one row.

let's say if I have row with the json value:

```
{"key1": "a", "key2": "b"}
```

Now, is it possible to extract the values as such: `["a", "b"]`?

I attempted this so far:

```
select ---- some sum() fields ----,
b.match_data::json -> jsonb_object_keys(b.match_data) as "Course"
from --- tables ---
join -- tables ---
where -- condition ---
group by -- sum() fields ----, b.match_data
```

The problem with this is that for json with multiple keys, it is returning multiple rows.

Comment: @S-Man hey sorry for the delay, I got busy at work. I took a hint from your answer to use an aggregator and came up with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S-Man's answer gave me a direction to use aggregators, and after a few trial and errors I got my answer

```
(select string_agg((select value from jsonb_array_elements_text(value)), ',')
from jsonb_each(b.match_data)) "Course"
```

It collects and displays values as `a, b,...` in one single row.

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ca05104727cc60abddc2682bbda08c27)

```
WITH jsondata AS (
    SELECT '{"key1": "a", "key2": "b"}'::jsonb as data  -- A
)
SELECT jsonb_agg(value)                                 -- C
FROM jsondata, jsonb_each(data)                         -- B
```

[Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), [Postgres (JSON) aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

A: CTE to work with your data

B: `jsonb_each` expands your data; result:

```
key    value
key1   "a"
key2   "b"
```

C: `jsonb_agg` aggregates the `value` column into a json array with the expected result: `["a", "b"]`.

---

If you do not want the result as json array but as normal text array you have to change `jsonb_each` into `jsonb_each_text` and `jsonb_agg` into `array_agg` (see fiddle)

---

I used `jsonb` as type. Of course all functions exist for type `json` as well.
([Postgres JSON types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html))